# Inverting a Sine Signal

Tags: oscillator, inverting-amplifier

I created a sinusoid signal(red) using the 555 timer in LTSpice. My goal is to flip this signal about the time axis (i.e. 180 degree phase shift)s so I thought I could use an Op Amp inverting amplifier to do. The resulting waveform (yellow-green) is somewhat like an inverted sinusoid but not exactly. What circuit should I build to successfully invert this sinusoid signal?
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you would start "looking" at the signal \$\frac 1 {2T} \$ later (in time), it would also be inverted. My point: inverting a signal is only useful if it is asymmetric (example: a 10% Duty Cycle PWM signal), which your signal is not (it has the same shape if multiplied by -1). **Or** the phase is relative to another signal, which I do not see that you have. Also my point: I do not see why you **need** to invert this sinewave. Please explain.

Comment: Your inverter circuit might also not work optimally because the **impedance** from which you feed the inverter the signal (the net named "Sine") is not **zero**. So there is some (complex) impedance in series with R2. For the inverter circuit to work properly the impedance of R2 needs to be the same as the impedance of R1.

Comment: I note that the 555 circuit uses ground and its own power source, so presumably the two circuits only share ground.  This will cause the offset of the inverted circuit as its input is necessarily already centred around about half of the 555 power supply.  The scope traces confirm this.  I also note that neither waveform looks sinusoidal except near the beginning where they are lower and not so "sharpened" visually.  I'd say your circuit is working as expected, except maybe that offset.  Raise the input on the op-amp + input by that amount and that should disappear, or tie the 555 ground to -9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [OP-07](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP07.pdf) is a great little device but not suitable for your application. The signal coming from the 555 and LC filter is about 10 kHz and has an amplitude of about 14 volts peak-to-peak and the slow OP-07 just cannot keep up. It's output is slew rate limited to typically 0.3 volts per μs: -

[image]

And that means a 14 volt change in output amplitude will take nearly 47 μs and might be as long as 140 μs. Bear in mind that 10 kHz has a period of 100 μs. So, what you get is a rather triangular shaped output waveform (as you can see if you look closely): -

[image]

> *What circuit should I build to successfully invert this sinusoid
> signal?*

A much quicker op-amp is the likely answer. Or, if you can live with a smaller amplitude sinewave, reduce the amplitude.